# Python максимальное значение с группировкой, учитывающее периоды до текущего

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Пытаюсь сделать столбец, который бы выводил последнюю дату, в которую наблюдалсь просрочка более 0

Датафрейм:

| Период | Договор займа | Дней в просрочке | debtm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 66590,54 |
| 04.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 66590,54 |
| 03.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 12 | 68341,54 |
| 02.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 11 | 68341,54 |
| 01.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 10 | 68341,54 |
| 30.09.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 66590,54 |
| 29.09.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 68341,54 |

Столбец:
`df['Просрочка'] = df[((df['ДнейВПросрочке'] > 0) & (df['debtm'] > 0))].groupby('ДоговорЗайма')['Период'].transform(max)`

Получаю последнюю дату с максимальной просрочкой, но только в тех строках, где соблюдается условие фильтрации. А как можно сделать, чтобы нужная дата выводилась во всех строках, где период меньше этой даты?

То есть хочу получить:

| Период | Договор займа | Дней в просрочке | debtm | Макс дата просрочки |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 66590,54 | NaT |
| 04.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 66590,54 | NaT |
| 03.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 12 | 68341,54 | 03.10.2022 |
| 02.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 11 | 68341,54 | 03.10.2022 |
| 01.10.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 10 | 68341,54 | 03.10.2022 |
| 30.09.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 66590,54 | 03.10.2022 |
| 29.09.2022 | 8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837 | 0 | 68341,54 | 03.10.2022 |

Подскажите, как можно дополнить или изменить код, чтобы получить нужный результат?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку у вас даты отсортированы, то можно применить после вашего кода `.ffill()` в группах по 'Договор займа':

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Период': ['05.10.2022', '04.10.2022', '03.10.2022', '02.10.2022', '01.10.2022', '30.09.2022', '29.09.2022',
                '05.10.2022', '04.10.2022', '03.10.2022', '02.10.2022', '01.10.2022', '30.09.2022', '29.09.2022'],
     'Договор займа': ['8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837', '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837', '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837', '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33837', '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838', '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838', '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838',
                       '8014005056A5512711ED094F00C33838'],
     'Дней в просрочке': [0, 0, 12, 11, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 10, 0, 0],
     'debtm': [66590.54, 66590.54, 68341.54, 68341.54, 68341.54, 66590.54, 68341.54, 66590.54, 66590.54, 68341.54,
               68341.54, 68341.54, 66590.54, 68341.54]})
df['Период'] = df['Период'].astype('datetime64')

df['Просрочка'] = df[((df['Дней в просрочке'] > 0) & (df['debtm'] > 0))].groupby('Договор займа')['Период'].transform(max)
df['Просрочка'] = df.groupby('Договор займа')['Просрочка'].ffill() # добавлено
print(df)
```